# Can't get print screen to work on dual monitor set up?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screenshot

I just got a new monitor so I'm using a dual monitor set up for extended desktop.

But I've noticed that when I try to print screen, it always captures the same monitor no matter what monitor I'm working on.

I googled it and a few pages said do alt+print screen
But that isn't working for me either.
It always captures my secondary monitor no matter what.
I'm on windows 8 so If I had to I could just use the snapshot program. But I'd rather just do it the same way I've been doing it for years.

Comment: What OS are you using? Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Print Screen captures the entire desktop, not just a single display. Special software (like the Snipping Tool) is required to capture only one display.